# limitation number of keys in memcached service

Tags: memcached, key

I wanna know is there any limitation for number of keys stored in memcached?
I want to manipulate many keys with small size in memcached. Is there any limiataion for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only store as many key/value pairs as will fit into memory in your memcached cluster. When memcached runs out of space it will evict keys using an LRU policy. If you don't want keys to be evicted then you can specify the -M parameter.

Comment: so there is no limitation for number of keys. just size of storage is limited, true ?

Comment: The storage size is limited and as a result that means the number of keys you can store in memcached is limited, but if you try to store a new key when memcached is full then memcached will just evict (delete) a key that has not been used for a while in order to make space. Does that make sense?

Comment: yeap, at all limitation is for size not number. if number of keys and vlaues fill memcached, then orlder keys will remove. clear ?